# How to sync Telegram contacts photo to Android contacts?

Tags: java, android, c++, telegram, android-contacts

How to sync **Telegram contacts photo** to Android contacts?

Is it possible by Telegram to send the profile photo of contacts to Android (Gmail) contacts?

***P.S.***

> I have verified Telegram for a feature for this purpose, but I could
> not find any features in the app also I have searched in the net but I
> could not find any apps for this purpose.
>
> I don't know why Telegram
> contacts profile photo could not add to Android contacts?  So I want to develop an app
> for this purpose.
> Do you have any clues?

Thanks

Comment: @Christopher I have verified Telegram for a feature for this purpose, but I could not find any feature in the app and I have searched in the net but I could not find any app for this purpose, I don't know why Telegram photo could not add to Android contacts. So I want to develop an app for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not supported in [Contacts API v3](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/). If you check the docs, there is no mention of this. File a feature request for this [here](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request).

Comment: Hi, it is amazing that Telegram doesn't have a feature for synchronizing its contacts photo to Android contacts. Has it a security reason?